# Unable to get the value returned

Tags: python, return, python-3.6

```
data=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,10]
def event(data):
    duration=0
    def delta(data):
        first=data[0]
        last=data[8]
        duration =last - first
        print(duration)

        return duration

    def division(duration):
        a=duration/3
        print(a)


    delta(data)
    print(duration)
    division(duration)

event(data)
```

The ouput I got is

> 9
>   
>   0
>   
>   0.0

The value 9 is not returned to duration,which was initialized to 0.Hence not able to compute division(duration) correctly

the output that i want is

> 9
>   
>   9
>   
>   3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To "get" the return value of a function, you need to either use it immediately or assign it (bind it to a name). Assignment is what you need here since you use the result twice. It is performed by the `=` operator. You could do something like this:

```
duration = delta(data)
print(duration)
division(duration)
```

Keep in mind that the `duration` you define in your `delta` function has nothing to do with the one in `event` because they are in different namespaces. If you want to be able to set `event`'s `duration` from `delta`, you can let Python know that you want to access something in an enclosing function using `nonlocal`. An alternative to having a return value from `delta` would be to add the following first line to it:

```
nonlocal duration
```

That being said, this is not the recommended solution. If is much better to keep your namespaces completely separate and just fix your return value assignment.

As a side note, consider redefining `last` as `last = data[-1]`. Python let's you index from the end of a list using negative indices.

Answer (score 0):

You should edit a line with `delta(data)` to `duration = delta(data)` as the return isn't being stored.

I've tested the code and it works with this modification.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that the description variable inside delta function is not same as the one you defined with `duration= 0`. inside a function its a local variable. So, either catch the return to duration or use a duration as a `global` variable. One more way is to just put `nonlocal duration` in delta function

change

```
delta(data)
print(duration)
division(duration)
```

to

```
duration=delta(data)
print(duration)
division(duration)
```

Comment: i used global duration inside the delta function but it is still not working. i dont knw if i am correct

Comment: you shoud create a  global outside the function and then use it inside again. but, i think that would be a bad thing here, as you have to use global two times, once in event function and one again in the delta function

Comment: But, i think there is one more way, try to use nonlocal, i just looked it up

Comment: @mad Physisct, has answerd it wonderfully, i think thats the best answer you can get